# Error connection to content manager with java api

Tags: java, db2-content-manager

After i configure and run SConnectDisconnectICM from api samples I get the below error.

```
com.ibm.mm.sdk.common.DKUsageError: DGL7332A: Library server representation type was not found. Please make sure that a valid library server and representation type has been specified in the cmbicmsrvs.ini file or to the Content Manager connector. : ICMNLSDB
```

Answer (score 0):

In the samples, by changing database to machinename I fixed error.

before :    public static String DEFAULT_DATABASE = "databasename";
after  :    public static String DEFAULT_DATABASE = "MACHINENAME";